# sizeof operator gives varied results for float

Tags: c++

```
float f=124.50;
cout<<sizeof(f);
cout<<sizeof(124.50);
```

Both the statements give different results.But works for int and char. why does it differ for float?

Comment: Because `124.50` is a `double`.

Comment: 124.50 is a double. Try 124.50f.

Comment: `sizeof(124.50f)` is what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`124.50` is a [*floating point literal*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) that produces a `double`, not a `float`. You need an `f` suffix to produce a `float`:

- `sizeof(124.5f)` will be equal to `sizeof(f)`.

Comment: This `is` pretty `easy` to `read`, in `my` opinion. `But` others `may` disagree

Comment: `g` `o` `o` `d` `p` `o` `i` `n` `t`

Answer (score 0):

In `cout<<sizeof(124.50);`, `124.50` is not a `float`.  It [floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) and it has the type `double`.  Unless you specify a suffix, all floating point literals are of type `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Because 124.50 is a double
By default, a literal constant is double, unless you define it float: 124.3F.

Prints 4.

```
std::cout << sizeof(123.4F);
```